# woocommerce paypal auto return not working

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

I configurated the whole woocommerce paypal accordingly to https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-standard/

I also tested the IPN and it seems to be working ( IPN simulator )

I'm working in sandbox mode.

The problem is that even if I set auto return section in paypal profile it does not return automatically after the payment is over.

Any clue?

PS: I noticed that in woocommerce orders are still in waiting for payment status.

Comment: Does it stay on the PayPal page?

Comment: I am going offline for several hours. I just want to tell you that I have used the PayPal Standard sandbox successfully for quite some time, including today. So, I think you have a configuration problem. This protocol is pretty simple so it should be easy to find out what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this sort of thing happens quite often with PayPal Standard in WooCommerce.  I would recommend switching to the [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) plugin and setting up Express Checkout.  It works better in general and has lots of features/options that Standard doesn't have.